# how to create equivalent for(int i=0, i<= collection.size() + 1, i++) in jstl

Tags: java, jstl, el

I have simple java code for getting number of all persons added/saved in DB and +1 for adding new person like :

```
for(int i=1, i<= collection.size() + 1, i++){
      <option value="<%=i>"/>"><%=i></option>
}
```

but Using JSTL I wanted to come up with :

```
<c:forEach items="${persons + 1}" var="person">
<option value="<c:out value="${person.personId}"/>">
    <c:out value="${person.personId}"/>
</option>
</c:forEach>
```

but this `${persons + 1}` gives me error. please help me in this case.

Answer (score 0):

ForEach in jstl is the same as foreach in java but just other Syntax:

```
for(Type : Collection ){
   //functionality
}
```

in which all your Collection value's  will be stored, one by one in a variable which consists of the predefined type Type.

So when you are trying to do `persons+1` it is only normal that you get an error because you cannot apply any math functions (+,-,*,/,...) on a Collection.

Think of it as this way:

- you can easly find the result of  **1+1**
- You can't find the result of **1+orange**

Comment: OK but I want to get size of collection, how how can I get that?